# How do I extract a tar file in nodejs using the pipeline() method?

Tags: node.js, pipeline, tar, unzip

My current code looks like this:

```
const gzip2 = zlib.createUnzip();
const pack2 = new tar.Unpack();
const source2 = Readable.from('public/img.tar.gz');
const destination2 = fs.createWriteStream('public/images2');
pipeline(source2, gzip2, pack2, destination2, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('An error occurred:', err);
        process.exitCode = 1;
    }
});
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
internal/streams/pipeline.js:108
  throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(
  ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "val" argument must be an instance of Readable, Iterable, or AsyncIterable. Received an instance of Unpack
    at makeAsyncIterable (internal/streams/pipeline.js:108:9)
    at pipeline (internal/streams/pipeline.js:265:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/index.js:39:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

I've also tried

```
const pack2 = tar.extract();
```

without luck.
If anyone can help me to extract this tar file using pipeline, so that I can also unzip the file. I would be very grateful. I've seen people use .pipe(tar.extract()) online, but I'm trying to keep my code as clean and uniform as possible. This: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar has unfortunately not been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const tar = require('tar.gz2')
var read = tar().createReadStream('/public/images');
var write = fs.createWriteStream('compressed.tar.gz');
pipeline(read,write,  
   (err) => {
   if (err) {
    throw err
   }
})
```

Comment: I'm getting this error,
"internal/streams/pipeline.js:77
    throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK(streams[streams.length - 1]);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received Unpack {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    at popCallback (internal/streams/pipeline.js:77:11)
    at pipeline (internal/streams/pipeline.js:144:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/Ethan/Dropbox/Koding/WebDev/MyWebsite/platform-land/index.js:52:1) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK'
}"
There was more, but it was too long to fit.

Comment: I'm going to assign you the bounty anyways, just because I don't want it to go to waste.

Comment: Edited callback function, should work now

Comment: I'm getting this error now, "error Error: unexpected end of file
    at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (zlib.js:181:17) {
  errno: -5,
  code: 'Z_BUF_ERROR'
}" Thank you for continuing to work on this, it looks like you're my only hope.

Comment: Done, Ethan. Tell me if there's any errors.

Comment: @TomEpsilon Note that code-only answers are always at risk of being deleted (it's currently in the peer review queue). It would be a good idea to add some brief explanations for why OP's code didn't work and why your code fixes it.

Comment: @TomEpsilon Here's the new error, "internal/streams/pipeline.js:77
    throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK(streams[streams.length - 1]);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received <ref *1> Gunzip {
...
at popCallback (internal/streams/pipeline.js:77:11)
    at pipeline (internal/streams/pipeline.js:144:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/index.js:63:1)
...
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK'
}"

Comment: We should move this discussion to chat.

Comment: @TomEpsilon there might be a solution to this, but I don't think we're going to get to it between the two of us, I'm just going to use a non-pipeline method for now, and I'll come back to this if someone else comes with a working solution.

Comment: @TomEpsilon, no it got another error. But this code, "tar.x({file: './public/img.tar.gz', C: './public/images'});" works for some reason. It does both the uncompressing and extracting at once.

Comment: Yes. It was designed to.